# R: 'data' object always exists?

Tags: r

I have a data set which is called 'data'. This is a data frame.

Since it takes long time to load, I check if this is not yet loaded before proceeding. So, I plan to use:

```
exists('data')
```

Unfortunately, it seems that this instruction always returns true:

```
> ls(all=TRUE)
character(0)
> exists('data')
[1] TRUE
> exists('mflskkl')
[1] FALSE
```

What did I miss?

Thanks.

Comment: Yet another reason to NOT use names for objects that are also function names. `data` is a function name so it "exists".

Answer (score 2):

Objects in R exist in many places. You need to decide where you are expecting that object to exist. In your case I guess you are testing if the object exists in the users default global environment. Read the help for `exists`, and you'll see you also need `inherits=FALSE` too.

```
> test2=function(){exists("data",envir=.GlobalEnv, inherits=FALSE)}
> test2()
[1] FALSE
> data=999
> test2()
[1] TRUE
> rm(data)
> test2()
[1] FALSE
```

Note this is all probably a wrong thing to do - better to pass objects as parameters to reusable functions than rely on things in the global environment. But I reckon you probably just have some big script rather than writing nice R code...